# torsocks command not working on Mac

Tags: macos, mac, tor

torsocks commands doesn't work on Mac. For example if I run:

```
torsocks http https://check.torproject.org/api/ip
```

It returns:

> 1546862950 PERROR torsocks[6434]: socks5 libc connect: Connection
>   refused (in socks5_connect() at socks5.c:202) 1546862950 PERROR
>   torsocks[6434]: socks5 libc connect: Connection refused (in
>   socks5_connect() at socks5.c:202)
>
> http: error: ConnectionError:
>   HTTPSConnectionPool(host='check.torproject.org', port=443): Max
>   retries exceeded with url: /api/ip (Caused by
>   NewConnectionError(': Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 4]
>   Non-recoverable failure in name resolution',)) while doing GET request
>   to URL: https://check.torproject.org/api/ip

The url is valid because when I do `curl https://check.torproject.org/api/ip`, it returns a valid response.

Comment: @Allan Yes I can, If I do `curl https://check.torproject.org/api/ip`, it returns a response.

Comment: Cool.  I wish I could assist further, but linking up to the TOR network on machines/networks I use for work is not something I wish to do.  Hopefully someone can assist further.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know much about Tor but I managed to get rid of the error by starting `tor` beforehand:

- `brew install tor torsocks`
- `cp /usr/local/etc/tor/torrc.sample /usr/local/etc/tor/torrc`
- Uncomment `ControlPort 9051` and `CookieAuthentication 1` in `/usr/local/etc/tor/torrc` and change `CookieAuthentication 1` to `CookieAuthentication 0`.
- `brew services start tor`

I'm using it successfully as follows:

- `brew install openssl`
- `torify /usr/local/opt/openssl/bin/openssl s_client -quiet -crlf -connect example.com:443`

Comment: /usr/bin/openssl. Why does it have to be installed again?

Comment: `torify openssl s_client -quiet -crlf -connect example.com:443` results in `ERROR: /usr/bin/openssl is located in a directory protected by Apple's System Integrity Protection.` There seem to be other workarounds, such as copying the pre-installed binary to a different location. Since I needed Brew's OpenSSL instead of Apple's LibreSSL for something else anyway, I opted for the approach above.